# Android : adding filters to javamail client

Tags: android, filter, jakarta-mail

In my android mail client app i am using javamail for imap /pop account.

I now want my app to support adding filters So that user can create filters like in gmail or other mail apps.
How do i do this using javamail api

Answer (score 1):

You can't create filters for incoming mail because you don't get control until the message is already stored in your INBOX.  When you look at the INBOX you can examine all the recent messages and "filter" them by moving them to other folders, etc.  That works fine if your application is the only application that ever looks at the INBOX, and there's only one instance of your application running.  Otherwise, multiple applications can see inconsistent or changing views of your messages.

Comment: i am looking fora way similar to what gmail app has. Like add filters to folders . I am not sure how it manages the filters